# Error: keystore.properties not found when cloning project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to clone a repository from GitHub. While importing the project I'm getting an error:

> E:\ProjectDir\keystore.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)

I've never encountered this problem when importing other repos from GitHub.

Comment: Look in your `build.gradle` files for references to `keystore.properties`. Then, either comment them out, or create a file in accordance with whatever your Gradle file needs from those properties.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. Commenting out the references worked!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Many projects configure signing of `release` builds by means of a `keystore.properties` file. That file would contain properties pointing to where the release keystore is, what passwords to use to access the release key, and so forth. That keystore and the properties files should not be committed to a public version control system.

Hence, when you check out the code from version control, that `keystore.properties` file will not exist, and Gradle will complain.

There are ways to set up a `build.gradle` file to avoid this sort of error, checking to see if the file exists and only using its contents if it does. Tactically, in your case, simply commenting out the `release` build instructions would suffice.

Answer (score 9):

Make text file named keystore.properties in the root of project and insert the 4 below parameters in it:

```
storeFile="relative path to your keystore file"
storePassword="keystore file pass"
keyAlias=
keyPassword=
```

then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the keystore path found in the app level  **build.gradle** file . remove all ***signingConfigs***  block

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

Also, remove in build-type block

```
release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

otherwise add jks in particular path